# Selenium does not work correctly with context_click and click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing UI tests for my QT app with selenium + qtwebdriver, and I have one moment in app, which I need to test: user can perform right mouse button click -> some menu showed up and user can click in this menu. I tried this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

import time

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:9517',
                          desired_capabilities={"browserStartWindow": "*", "reuseUI": True})

driver.get("qtwidget://MainWindow")
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_by_offset(7, 87).context_click().move_by_offset(10, 91).click().perform()
```

Context menu appears (so it means, that right button click was performed well, but left mouse click was not performed. How to fix this ? Or maybe I can use other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'ARROW_DOWN' to select the option after clicking context click.

action.move_by_offset(7,87).context_click().contextClick().sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();